# jQuery.post() calling function with parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been searching around the web for this but it doesn't seems there's any topic like this (or maybe I am searching in the wrong direction).

Currently I have a jQuery file which will retrieve 9 additional posts from the database and append to the current posts listing.

**File: load-more.js**

```
var data = {
    action: 'be_ajax_load_more(tv)', // <-- this is the function in functions.php
    nonce: beloadmore.nonce,
    page: page,
    query: beloadmore.query
};

$.post(beloadmore.url, data, function(res) {
    ... code function to handle additional posts
}
```

**File: functions.php**

```
function be_ajax_load_more($category) {
    check_ajax_referer( 'be-load-more-nonce', 'nonce' );

    error_log( 'Made it into the be_ajax_load_more function');
    error_log($category);  // <-- this value is empty

    return morePosts;
}
```

It works perfectly fine if I change both the value of data.action = 'be_ajax_load_more' and function be_ajax_load_more() that receives no parameter, but once I added the parameter, the .post function doesn't recognise it.

Am I passing the parameter correctly? I even tried adding a new key value into my data array:

```
var data = {
    action: 'be_ajax_load_more',
    category: 'tv',
    nonce: beloadmore.nonce,
    page: page,
    query: beloadmore.query
};
```

But I am not sure how to get that data.category in my functions.php, can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You second JS setting is more in the right direction, your biggest failure seems in misunderstanding how ajax requests are handled on the WP PHP/server side.

On the PHP side, an action is being triggered based on the action parameter in your AJAX request. Since this is a generic mechanism it doesn't have any facilities to "guess" how many parameters are being passed or their order (probably something could have been developed to do that, but the current core code doesn't do it). Therefor the best you can get is to trigger the call to the `be_ajax_load_more` function when the request is received.

In the function itself you need to read from `$_POST` the relevant fields to get the parameter. IIRC this should be something like `$_POST['category']` which should give you the value `'tv'`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm getting the parameter now.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the data value to a variable (`$formdata`) then can access the data you like as:

```
parse_str( $_POST[ 'data' ], $formdata );
$category = $formdata[ 'category' ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are simply passing the parameters in wrong manner and because of this you are getting error.

Always go to the basics when you get some error in your code. This will help you to find when you did wrong. You have to pass parameters to the jQuery Post() method.

> This is how to do it:

```
$.post("result.php",
    {
        name: $("#name").val(),
        age: $("#age").val()
    })
```

Here name and age are input of type text controls. See some examples of using this method as given on this **[jQuery Post](http://www.yogihosting.com/jquery-post/)** tutorial which also tells that you can use the .fail() and .done() event on this method.

So in your case you can use the .fail() deferred event to find out what error you are getting on your code.

**Note** – you can also use Chrome browsers console window to find out these errors.